# junit2html Command not Recognized

Tags: python, python-behave

I have already installed junit2html and when I try to install again, it says requirement already satisfied.

But when I run actual command to convert XML to HTML, it says command not recognized.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to convert your .xml jnuit report to html report, using below command.

```sh
python -m junit2htmlreport <reportptah/name>.xml
```

It will generate an HTML report at the same location/name as junit report.